AddressSanitizer: alloc-dealloc-mismatch (operator new vs free) on exception
Minimum code.cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        throw std::runtime_error("blah");
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

On WSL Ubuntu 22.04. Compiled with:
clang++-20 -stdlib=libc++ -fsanitize=address -std=c++23 code.cpp

Running it, generates:
blah
=================================================================
==89869==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: alloc-dealloc-mismatch (operator new vs free) on 0x7be9594e0040
    #0 0x55db012e9a06 in free (/mnt/c/Users/XXX/OneDrive/Desktop/CPP/a+0xcfa06) (BuildId: 86f094d32b8073486e9ac3a7c6a9d0643854ed87)
    #1 0x7fb95a39f59b in std::range_error::~range_error() (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++abi.so.1+0x2959b) (BuildId: d7d99734f2d87018ea9a00655e07f5ed15b68b04)
    #2 0x7fb95a3a18a3 in __cxa_end_catch (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++abi.so.1+0x2b8a3) (BuildId: d7d99734f2d87018ea9a00655e07f5ed15b68b04)
    #3 0x55db0132f6fd in main (/mnt/c/Users/XXX/OneDrive/Desktop/CPP/a+0x1156fd) (BuildId: 86f094d32b8073486e9ac3a7c6a9d0643854ed87)
    #4 0x7fb95a047d8f in __libc_start_call_main csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:16
    #5 0x7fb95a047e3f in __libc_start_main csu/../csu/libc-start.c:392:3
    #6 0x55db01247474 in _start (/mnt/c/Users/XXX/OneDrive/Desktop/CPP/a+0x2d474) (BuildId: 86f094d32b8073486e9ac3a7c6a9d0643854ed87)

0x7be9594e0040 is located 0 bytes inside of 29-byte region [0x7be9594e0040,0x7be9594e005d)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x55db0132d1fd in operator new(unsigned long) (/mnt/c/Users/XXX/OneDrive/Desktop/CPP/a+0x1131fd) (BuildId: 86f094d32b8073486e9ac3a7c6a9d0643854ed87)
    #1 0x7fb95a40e05f in std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*) (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so.1+0x5b05f) (BuildId: 00e94063b8101dfae8b51b968ad9cd5aafda4a15)
    #2 0x7fb95a047d8f in __libc_start_call_main csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:16

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: alloc-dealloc-mismatch (/mnt/c/Users/XXX/OneDrive/Desktop/CPP/a+0xcfa06) (BuildId: 86f094d32b8073486e9ac3a7c6a9d0643854ed87) in free
==89869==HINT: if you don't care about these errors you may set ASAN_OPTIONS=alloc_dealloc_mismatch=0
==89869==ABORTING

-stdlib=libc++ is included for std::print() in the rest of code, removing it does stop alloc-dealloc-mismatch.
Is there something can be done to prevent alloc-dealloc-mismatch?
Or this is simply expected for in "development" clang-20 and lib++-20-dev? and just need to be reported somewhere...
Thanks!

Don't see anything like this in clang 19. At least you can take comfort in in this case it's not always your fault

In this case this must be short between keyboard and the seat. Just dropped to clang-19 and lib++-19-dev and still getting ASAN error... Will investigate more...

I think this is probably the problem that is explained in detail here.

Above looks like a good candidate. I'll admit to not having spun up an Ubuntu box. Maybe there's just something weird in the secret sauce.

Yes, above should be the problem. I've seen at least 1 other recent question with the same root cause. You can try static linking libc++ as an imperfect fix.

@Xellos -static-libstdc++ indeed does prevent it.

Ha! That's how I missed it. My default build instructions statically link. I should have followed the asker's command line closely.
